# JDBC CallableStatement Stored Procedure CURSOR result set fetch

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I want to export huge data from `oracle` to csv file. so i used simple `JDBC` select statement to get data in memory but and then write it to file, But data is very large of i am getting Out of memory exception. So i thought of using  `CallableStatement` to call Stored Procedure which will return `CURSOR` with `ResultSet` as below :-

```
String getDBTableCursorSql = "{call getDBTableCursor(?,?)}";
callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(getDBTableCursorSql);
callableStatement.setString(1, "test");
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);

// execute getDBTableCursorSqlstore procedure
callableStatement.executeUpdate();

// get cursor and cast it to ResultSet
rs = (ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(2);

// loop it like normal 
while (rs.next()) {
    String userid = rs.getString("ID");
    String userName = rs.getString("NAME");
..
..
}
```

Oracle Proc :-

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getDBTableCursor(
           p_username IN DBUSER.USERNAME%TYPE,
           c_dbuser OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
    IS
    BEGIN

      OPEN c_dbuser FOR
      SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE USERNAME LIKE p_username || '%';

    END;
```

**Question 1** :- 
does above `ResultSet` will fetch all the data in single shot ? or it will go to database for each `rs.next()`,

**Question 2**:- 
is there any other approach which can deal with large data export to file in java using chunks so it wont get Out of memory issue?

I can't use pagination in this condition because of requirement.

Comment: within the loop we flush it. so we can save memory.

Comment: There is no reason that a normal select and writing in a loop would cause you to go out of memory. You might want to consider posting a question with the original problem as well, with the full code you use to write this.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question: the Oracle jdbc driver by default fetches 10 rows at a time. This can be verified or set to other value via standard jdbc:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/resltset.htm#JJDBC28621